# Can't get property from another class

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a class `RootViewController` where I have a `UIBarButtonItem` declared.  The method to display it is in another class `FirstDetailViewController`.

I am trying to access it in another class `SecondDetailViewController`, but it is always null. I tested with some other variables and they were null as well.  Here's what I have:

**RootViewController.h**

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;
...
@end
```

---

**RootViewController.m**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "FirstDetailViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize popoverController, splitViewController, rootPopoverButtonItem;

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {

    NSLog(@"splitviewController will hide");

    // Keep references to the popover controller and the popover button, and tell the detail view controller to show the button.
    barButtonItem.title = @"Menu";
    self.popoverController = pc;
    self.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:rootPopoverButtonItem];
}
```

---

**FirstDetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    NSLog(@"show root popover button item");

    // Add the popover button to the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
    [itemsArray release];
}
```

---

**SecondDetailViewController.h**

```
    #import "RootViewController.h"

    @class RootViewController;

    @interface SecondDetailViewController : UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> {
    ...
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *root;
    @end
```

---

**SecondDetailViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondDetailViewController.h"

@implementation SecondDetailViewController

@synthesize root;

...
NSLog(@"view class : %@", [root.splitViewController class]);
[detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:root.rootPopoverButtonItem];
...
```

Comment: where did you declare detailViewController in SecondDetailViewController?

Comment: add an assert to verify that barButtonItem is not nil in - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {
Likewise assert(root) in your SecondDetailViewController. Using lots of asserts can help you find these problems yourself.

Comment: Just a guess, you didn't set up the bar button item before you tried to access it.

Comment: @lu yuan, I declare it locally in the secondDetailViewController, and I can get its view, I am just trying to display the button

Comment: @Dustin can you provide an example?  I am fairly new to Objective-C and am not sure if i have set up the button or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably aren't setting the "root" property of SecondDetailViewController to the instance of RootViewController that you want to access the UIBarButtonItem for.  Then you're reading an uninitialized instance of RootViewController in your SecondDetailViewController code, and the only reason you don't get an error is that Objective C silently ignores calls to methods on nil objects (in this case the rootPopoverButtonItem getter method, which the `root.rootPopoverButtonItem` is shorthand for).

If your instance of "RootViewController" is called "myRootViewController", then somewhere in your code you have to do something like:

```
SecondDetailViewController *mySecondDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] init];
mySecondDetailViewController.root = myRootViewController;
```

Then you'll be accessing the copy of RootViewController that has the bar button you want.